# Time complexity of 3Sum Smaller

Tags: algorithm, big-o

A problem called [3Sum Smaller](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum-smaller/#/description) on LeetCode asks:

> Given an array of `n` integers `nums` and a `target`, find the number of index triplets `i, j, k` with `0 <= i < j < k < n` that satisfy the condition `nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] < target`.
>
> Could you solve it in O(n^2) runtime?

And a common O(n^2) [solution people agree upon](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/23421/simple-and-easy-understanding-o-n-2-java-solution) is:

```
public class Solution {
    int count;
    
    public int threeSumSmaller(int[] nums, int target) {
        count = 0;
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        int len = nums.length;
    
        for(int i=0; i<len-2; i++) {
            int left = i+1, right = len-1;
            while(left < right) {
                if(nums[i] + nums[left] + nums[right] < target) {
                    count += right-left;
                    left++;
                } else {
                    right--;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return count;
    }
}
```

**I do not understand how this could be O(n^2).** Sure, the algorithm uses some handy shortcuts to save time (primarily by sorting and using that to our advantage), but I don's see how it still ensures O(n^2).

**Is there some mathematical reason this is O(n^2) rather than O(n^3)**, and if so, could you please explain the principles behind it so I can spot the behavior again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way of determining this is an n^2 algorithm is looking at the loops.

The outer (for) loop iterates at most n times (technically n-2 but whatever). The inner loop depends on the values of left, and right.
left is at LEAST 1, right is at MOST len = n (technically len-1 but whatever) the inner loop only executes if `left < right`, so in the worst case scenario the inner loop iterates at MOST n times.

The outer loop iterates at most n times. For every iteration of the outer loop the inner loop iterates at most n times. The algorithm is O(n^2). Also this algorithm IS O(n^3) since O(n^2)=O(n^3).

The other statement which doesn't run in constant time is:

```
Arrays.sort(nums);
```

Assuming an efficient sorting algorithm, this operation runs in O(nlog n) which is in O(n^2) so it does not affect the final time complexity.

A trick when doing time complexity analysis. Forget about what the algorithm is supposed to do and look only at loops and how much they could potentially run.

Comment: This helps. So, specifically, the worst case for the inner loop is n steps, because either `j` will move all the way right in search of a value small enough or `k` will move all the way left, continually finding valid sums. Also, `j` and `k` never cross, so again it only could be `n` steps for each `i` in the outer loop.

Comment: As I said, I didn't even look at the logic of the code at all, I only looked at the loop guards and related statements. Why the for loop iterates n times is obvious I assume. The way I traced the inner loop is as follows:
left depends on i, i is at least 0 and never less, so left is at least 1. right is always at most len-1. As the outer loop iterates left increases and it never decreases (trivially) so the inner loop will run until left>=right, which happens in at most n iterations.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Solution {
    int count; //constant operation

    public int threeSumSmaller(int[] nums, int target) {
        count = 0; //constant operation
        Arrays.sort(nums); //sorting is generally considered O(nlogn)
        int len = nums.length; //constant operation

        for(int i=0; i<len-2; i++) { //O(n) operation
            int left = i+1, right = len-1; //two constant operations
            while(left < right) { //O(n) operation
                if(nums[i] + nums[left] + nums[right] < target) { //constant operation
                    count += right-left; //constant operation
                    left++; //constant operation
                } else { 
                    right--; //constant operation
                }
            }
        }
        return count; //constant operation
    }
}
```

Above I have commented out your code block with the basic running times of each line. As you can see, there are two O(n) operations and a O(nlogn) operation. Sorting is generally assumed to be O(nlogn). Your function performs this operation once per call. The O(n) operations are nested, so for the first N operation, it performs N subsequent operations. This is O(n^2). Your program is O(nlogn) + O(n^2), which makes it O(n^2) total, as only the highest order term matters.

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 7] target: 11 is giving me 1. the answer should be 2.

1 ,2 ,3
1, 2, 7